# Defining area by the Riemann integral, how to prove the area of a region is preserved under rotations?

Tags: calculus, geometry

If one uses the Riemann integral as the definition of area, how does one prove the that area of a region in the plane doesn't change if the region is rotated?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables